# Reading from device files

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Is there a specific approach to reading device files in CL? I try the following code in SBCL but it does not appear to work:

```
(defparameter modem #p"/dev/ttyUSB2")
(defun read-modem()
  (with-open-file (fd modem :direction :io :if-exists :append)
          (loop while (peek-char nil fd) do
            (format t "~A" (read-line fd))
            (finish-output fd))))
```

I know there's output because `cat /dev/ttyUSB2` shows it.

Comment: can you read characters instead of lines?

Comment: Reading characters works. Makes sense now, read-line only returns when it encounters #\newline or end-of-file.

Comment: Note also that NEWLINE can mean CR, CRLF (two characters!) or LF - depending on Lisp, the Lisp configuration and platform.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you need to read from them as from binary files.  For instance, here's what I read from `/dev/urandom`:

```
> (with-open-file (fd "/dev/urandom" :direction :io :if-exists :append
                      :element-type 'unsigned-byte) 
    (read-byte fd))
161
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is with buffering.
I don't think you can turn it off in CL `open`, so I am afraid you have to use `sb-unix:unix-open` and `sb-unix:unix-read`.